# How to create a people's graph

Tags: r, plot

I'm new using R because I started using it for my degree in International Relations.

I'm very interested in knowing if there is any way to represent graphically with a "People Infographic" as the picture below.

[image: INFOGRAFIC]

Comment: Yes there is, see [the waffle package](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/waffle).